# Regex for starting with alphanumeric and hyphen, underscore later in string

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to write a regexp in golang that matches strings that start as alphanumeric and can have an underscore or hyphen after, but not starting with a hyphen or underscore.

Here is what I could come up with, but this matches alphanumeric and hyphen underscore anywhere

```
[A-Za-z0-9_-]
```

So something like sea-food would match or seafood or sea_food, but not -seafood nor _seafood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a `^` to indicate the start of the string and `$` for the end, and then use two character classes:

`^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_-]*$`

To disallow hyphens and underscores at the end of the string as well try:

`^[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9_-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?$`

Comment: Thanks, i don't know why I didn't think of two character classes.

Comment: np. Keep in mind that this allows hyphens and underscores at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple. You could use a negative lookahead at the start.

```
^(?![_-])[\w-]+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qB0fQ7/1)

Comment: Great answer! How would you extend it to not allow hyphens and underscores at the end?

Comment: simple , `^(?![_-])(?!.*[-_]$)[\w-]+$` but i don't know whether go lang supports negative lookahead or not..

Comment: Slick. Leading with the negative lookahead with a `$` in it (rather than placing it at the end) is not intuitive, but it makes sense now that I see it. And, you called it, no support from golang for lookahead/behind...

Comment: For reference: http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/  and  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/7qgSDWPIh_E

Comment: Go doesn't support lookaheads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split up your expression, and match the first character separately, and do the following:

[A-Za-Z][A-Za-z0-9_-]*